# Lexx and Yacc parsing in C with c syntax into symbol table

Tags: bison, yacc, lex

I am trying to create a c type parser with bison and lex. Yes this is for a school assignment but i am soo lost and I do the school online so I do not get much help. I need this to parse the information into a table but I'm pretty sure there are errors in my parse.y file as it does not load the information into the table it says there is no code. I know my .y file is missing some grammer but i would think that some of this should load into the symbol table as it is.

The output when running the make file which is:

```
default:
    clear
    yacc -d -v --debug parse.y
    lex -l scan.l
    gcc -o cfc symtab.c lex.yy.c y.tab.c
clean:
    $(RM) cfc *.o lex.yy.c parse.tab.c y.tab.h y.output dump.symtab
```

Output to screen:

```
> yacc -d -v --debug parse.y parse.y:39 parser name defined to default
> :"parse" conflicts:  2 reduce/reduce lex -l scan.l gcc -o cfc symtab.c
> lex.yy.c y.tab.c
```

Passing 60.cf through the parser:

```
> semantic error cnt: 0     lines of code: -1
```

The results from the parser is that the symbol table is empty and here is what the output says:

```
> Starting parse 
> Entering state 0 
> Reading a token: Next token is 292 (INT)
> parse error: line 0: Shifting error token, Entering state 1
> Reducing via rule 3 (line 57), error  -> block
```

The example code to load 60.cf:

```
int foo()
{
    while ( i >= 0 )  {
       i = i * 1;
       c = c + 1;
    } 
    if ( c >= 0 )  
    { ; }
    else
    { i = 7; 
      c = i;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Here is the scan.l file:

```
%option yylineno

%{
#ifndef TRUE
#define TRUE 1 
#endif

#ifndef FALSE 
#define FALSE 0 
#endif

#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "symtab.h"
#include "y.tab.h"

int badtoken_cnt = 0;
int token_cnt = 0;
int col_cnt = 0;
int lineno = 0;

%}

comment     \/\*([^*]|\n)*\*\/
digit       [0-9]
ichar       [A-Z_a-z]
integer     {digit}+
newline     \n
strchar     ([ ~]|\\n)
identifier  {ichar}([0-9]|{ichar})*
whitespace  [ \t]+
float       ([+-]?{digit}+)?\.{digit}*(e?[+-]?{digit}+)?
chrliteral  '([!*]|\\n)'
nullstring  \"\"
escquote    [^"]*\\\"[^"]*
strliteral  \"[^"]*{escquote}*\"
%%

"if"            { return IF;}
"then"          { return THEN;}
"else"          { return ELSE;}
"while"         { return WHILE;}
"return"        { return RETURN;}
"break"         { return GOTO;}
"goto"          { return GOTO;}
"read"          { return READ;}
"write"         { return WRITE;}
"float"         { return REAL;}
"int"           { return INT;}
"void"          { return VOID;}
"char"          { return CHAR;}

"="             { return ASSIGN;}
"!="            { return NE;}
"=="            { return EQ;}
"<"             { return LT;}
"<="            { return LE;}
">"             { return GT;}
">="            { return GE;}
"&&"            { return AND;}
"||"            { return OR;}

"+"             { return PLUS;}
"-"             { return MINUS;}
"*"             { return TIMES;}
"/"             { return OVER;}
"%"             { return MOD;}

"{"             { return LBRACE;}
"}"             { return RBRACE;}
"["             { return LBRACK;}
"]"             { return RBRACK;}
"("             { return LPAREN;}
")"             { return RPAREN;}
";"             { return SEMI;}
","             { return COMMA;}

{float}         { 
                  yylval.tokname = malloc(sizeof(yytext));
                  strncpy(yylval.tokname,yytext,yyleng);
                  printf("yylval: %s\n",yylval.tokname);
                  insert(yytext, yyleng, REAL_TYPE, lineno);
                  printf("yytext: %s\n",yytext);
                  return FLOAT;
                }
{integer}       { 
                  yylval.tokname = malloc(sizeof(yytext));
                  printf("yylval: %s\n",yylval.tokname);
                  strncpy(yylval.tokname,yytext,yyleng);
                  insert(yytext, yyleng, INT_TYPE, lineno);
                  printf("yytext: %s\n",yytext); 
                  return INTEGER;
                }


{chrliteral}    { 
                  yylval.tokname = malloc(sizeof(yytext));
                  strncpy(yylval.tokname,yytext,yyleng);
                  printf("yylval: %s\n",yylval.tokname);
                  insert(yytext, yyleng, -1, lineno);
                  printf("yytext: %s\n",yytext);
                  return CHRLIT;
                }

{nullstring}    { 
                  yylval.tokname = malloc(sizeof(yytext));
                  strncpy(yylval.tokname,yytext,yyleng);
                  printf("yylval: %s\n",yylval.tokname);
                  insert(yytext, yyleng, -1, lineno);
                  printf("yytext: %s\n",yytext);
                  return STRLIT;
                }

{strliteral}    { 
                  yylval.tokname = malloc(sizeof(yytext));
                  strncpy(yylval.tokname,yytext,yyleng);
                  printf("yylval: %s\n",yylval.tokname);
                  insert(yytext, yyleng, STR_TYPE, lineno);
                  printf("yytext: %s\n",yytext);
                  return STRLIT;
                }

{identifier}    { 

                  return IDENT;
                }
{newline}       { col_cnt = 1; }

{whitespace}    { col_cnt+=yyleng; }

{comment}       { col_cnt = 0; }

"//"            { /* handle C++ style comments */
                    char c;
                    do { c = input();
                    } while (c != '\n');
                    lineno++;
                }

.               { return ERROR;}

%%
```

Here is the parse.y file, which is where I believe the errors are:

```
%{

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "symtab.h"

#define DEBUG 0
#define TRUE 1
#define FALSE 0
#define MAX_MSG_LEN 50
#define YYDEBUG 1

int errcnt = 0;
char errmsg[40];
extern char *yytext;
extern FILE *yyin;
extern FILE *yyout;
extern int yyparse();
extern int lineno;
int yydebug = 1;
int t;
%}

/* no warning for fewer than 1 shift/reduce conflicts and 0 reduce/reduce */ 
%expect 1 
%union { int tokid;
         char *tokname;
       }

%token <tokname> IDENT NUMBER
%token <tokid> ASSIGN PLUS LBRACE RBRACE LPAREN RPAREN SEMI ERROR FLOAT INTEGER 
/* ADDED */
%token <tokid> IF THEN ELSE WHILE RETURN GOTO READ WRITE VOID CHAR
/* ADDED */
%token <tokid> NE EQ LT LE GT GE AND OR MINUS TIMES OVER MOD INT REAL
/* ADDED */
%token <tokid> LBRACK RBRACK COMMA CHRLIT STRLIT
%type <tokid> block stmt_seq stmt decl expr term assignmnt decltype error

%start block

%% 

block       : LBRACE stmt_seq RBRACE  
            | LPAREN stmt_seq RPAREN  
            | error { yyerrok; return 0; } 
            ;

stmt_seq    : stmt_seq stmt SEMI
            | stmt SEMI
            | error  { yyerrok; return 0;} 
            ;

stmt        : expr
            | decl
            | assignmnt { $$ = $1; }
            | error  { yyerrok; return 0;} 
            ;

decl        : decltype IDENT { 
                setType($2,$1);
                fprintf(stdout,"set decltype to: %d for %s\n",$$,$2);  
            }
            ;

expr        : expr PLUS term 
              { /* add constraint here */ }

            | term { $$ = $1; } 
            | error    { yyerrok; return 0;} 
            ;

assignmnt   : IDENT ASSIGN expr  
              { /* add constraint here */ }
            ;

term        : NUMBER { $$ = lookupType($1); }

            | IDENT  { $$ = lookupType($1); }
            ;

decltype    : INTEGER  { $$ = INT_TYPE; }
            | FLOAT { $$ = REAL_TYPE; }
            ;

%%

int main( int argc,char *argv[] )
{
   strcpy(errmsg,"type error\n");
   int i;
   if(argc < 2) {
      printf("Usage: ./cfc <source filename>\n");
      exit(0);
   }
   FILE *fp = fopen(argv[1],"r");
   if(!fp) {
     printf("Unable to open file for reading\n");
     exit(0);
   }
   yyin = fp;

   fp = fopen("dump.symtab","w");
   if(!fp) {
     printf("Unable to open file for writing\n");
     exit(0);
   }

   int flag = yyparse();

   /* dump symtab for debugging if necessary  */
   symtab_dump(fp);  
   lineno--;  /* don't count the last newline */ 
   printf("\nsemantic error cnt: %d \tlines of code: %d\n",errcnt,lineno);

   /* cleanup */
   fclose(fp);
   fclose(yyin);

   return flag;
}


yywrap()
{
   return(1);
}

int yyerror(char * msg)
{ fprintf(stderr,"%s: line %d: \n",msg,lineno);
  return 0;
}
```

And in case you need it, here is the symbol table that I'm using:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "symtab.h"

/* maximum size of hash table */
#define SIZE 200 
#define MAXTOKENLEN 40

/* power of two multiplier in hash function */
#define SHIFT 4

/* the hash function */
static int hash ( char * key )
{ int temp = 0;
  int i = 0;
  while (key[i] != '\0')
  { temp = ((temp << SHIFT) + key[i]) % SIZE;
    ++i;
  }
  return temp;
}

/* a linked list of references (line nos) for each variable */
typedef struct RefListRec { 
     int lineno;
     struct RefListRec * next;
     /* ADDED */
     int type;
} * RefList;


/* hash entry holds variable name and its reference list */
typedef struct HashRec { 
     char st_name[MAXTOKENLEN];
     int st_size;
     RefList lines;
     int st_value;
     /* ADDED */
     int st_type;
     struct HashRec * next;
} * Node;

/* the hash table */
static Node hashTable[SIZE];

 /* insert an entry with its line number - if entry
  *  already exists just add its reference line no.  
  */
void insert( char * name, int len, int type, int lineno )
{ 
  /* ADDED */
  /*int len = strlen(name);*/
  int h = hash(name);
  Node l =  hashTable[h];
  while ((l != NULL) && (strcmp(name,l->st_name) != 0))
    l = l->next;
  if (l == NULL) /* variable not yet in table */
  { l = (Node) malloc(sizeof(struct HashRec));
    strncpy(l->st_name, name, len);  
    /* ADDED */
    l->st_type = type;
    l->lines = (RefList) malloc(sizeof(struct RefListRec));
    l->lines->lineno = lineno;
    l->lines->next = NULL;
    l->next = hashTable[h];
    hashTable[h] = l; }
  else /* found in table, so just add line number */
  { RefList t = l->lines;
    while (t->next != NULL) t = t->next;
    t->next = (RefList) malloc(sizeof(struct RefListRec));
    t->next->lineno = lineno;
    t->next->next = NULL;
  }
} 

/* return value (address) of symbol if found or -1 if not found */
int lookup ( char * name )
{ int h = hash(name);
  Node l =  hashTable[h];
  while ((l != NULL) && (strcmp(name,l->st_name) != 0))
    l = l->next;
  if (l == NULL) return -1;
  else return l->st_value;
}

/* return type value of symbol or -1 if symbol not found */
int lookupType( char * name )
{
  int h = hash(name);
  Node l =  hashTable[h];
  while ((l != NULL) && (strcmp(name,l->st_name) != 0))
    l = l->next;
  if (l == NULL) return -1;
  else return l->st_type;
}

/* set datatype of symbol returns 0 if symbol not found */
int setType( char * name, int t )
{
   int h = hash(name);
   Node l =  hashTable[h];
   while ((l != NULL) && (strcmp(name,l->st_name) != 0))
     l = l->next;
   if (l == NULL) return -1;
   else {
     l->st_type = t;
     return 0;
   }
}

/* print to stdout by default */ 
void symtab_dump(FILE * of) {  
  int i;
  fprintf(of,"------------ ------ ------------\n");
  fprintf(of,"Name         Type   Line Numbers\n");
  fprintf(of,"------------ ------ -------------\n");
  for (i=0; i < SIZE; ++i)
  { if (hashTable[i] != NULL)
    { Node l = hashTable[i];
      while (l != NULL)
      { RefList t = l->lines;
        fprintf(of,"%-12s ",l->st_name);

        if (l->st_type == INT_TYPE)
           fprintf(of,"%-7s","int ");
        if (l->st_type == REAL_TYPE)
           fprintf(of,"%-7s","real");
        if (l->st_type == STR_TYPE)
           fprintf(of,"%-7s","string");


        while (t != NULL)
        { fprintf(of,"%4d ",t->lineno);
          t = t->next;
        }
        fprintf(of,"\n");
        l = l->next;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You should provide some output from your program when you run it. For example, what does the parser say failed? It also looks like your start rule,  block, is only going to match a few things. Think about what it can match.

Comment: Yep, your start rule is block, which expects either an LBRACE or LPAREN token as the first token. Your test file starts with a different token--"int". So, your parser never gets past the first token. I'm not sure how much of the C grammar you plan to implement, but your start state needs something to capture that function header (assuming your grammar only has one function definition). Think of a  simplified C program, ignoring includes, function prototypes. The program is essentially as list of functions, where each function is a function header and then a block, where each block is ...

Comment: I need to implement everything in the scan.l file. Thanks for input trying some new things now lets see how it goes

Comment: although if anyone else some examples/more comments on what i need to do that is always welcome

Comment: @Brandon I have a question about your code. I want to write a simple compiler. Now i am working on scanner using flex. But the problem is that when I write 123abc I except it to report an error. but unfortunately it reports 123 as integer and abc as id. what's the solution? can you please help me?

Comment: @Brandon I have a question about your code. I want to write a simple compiler. Now i am working on scanner using flex. But the problem is that when I write 123abc I except it to report an error. but unfortunately it reports 123 as integer and abc as id. what's the solution? can you please help me?

Comment: @Brandon Hey man! Do you have the complete code? I'm trying to do the same, but I am completely lost

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The conflict occurs because of competing `error` productions. Your `stmt` derives `error`. But `stmt` also derives `expr` which derives `error`. Drop the one inside `expr`.

Have a look at the `y.output` file that `yacc` produced (because you passed `-v`).

Your grammar cannot possibly match the input program because your start symbol derives a brace- or parenthesis-enclosed block of statements, and not a sequence of external function definitions. You need to add the pieces of the grammar which will process a function definition: `decltype IDENT arglist body`, and so on.

One little thing that immediately stands out:

```
comment     \/\*([^*]|\n)*\*\/
```

You're saying that comments cannot contain asterisks.

A regex to match real C comments is: `[/][*]([^*]|[*]*[^*/])*[*]+[/]` (but note that this doesn't take into account Lex's conventions for newline).

You do not need to give token names to single character tokens. This only adds verbiage to the grammar, where you have to write things like LBRACE instead of just '{'.

Comment: @Kaz I have a question about your code. I want to write a simple compiler. Now i am working on scanner using flex. But the problem is that when I write 123abc I except it to report an error. but unfortunately it reports 123 as integer and abc as id. what's the solution? can you please help me?

Comment: @Linda One way to attack that problem is to match `123abc` with a separate rule, whose action is to signal an error like "trailing junk in integer token". Your `integer` and `id` rules work independently of this.